# Whats a more object oriented way to execute a python script

Tags: python

The following code cd's into the scrape folder, and enters the command "scrapy crawl yellow". It works well, however i want to make this more object oriented looking, utilizing something like

```
 if__name__== "__main__"
```

not sure how to implement this kind of code. Ultimately i want this to be an executable which is why im trying to make it more object oriented.

**App.py**

```
import os
import subprocess 

cw = os.getcwd()
path = '/scrape'
ourPath = cw + os.path.join(path)

if(ourPath):
    os.chdir(ourPath)
    os.system('scrapy crawl yellow')
```

Comment: This code makes no sense. How could `ourPath` ever be false? What are you really trying to achieve with this code, and why? Please explain, and also retitle the question to state the task accomplished by the code, as per the [ask] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of OOP as being a method to promote reuse by decomposing large data sets into types which tell how to handle their own data, and which can inherit or be inherited to make more complex types without having to duplicate or rewrite the more basic methods of handling the smaller data structures.

That said, you don't really declare any classes or other structures in here, so there isn't a way to make this more "Object Oriented".

You can make it a bit more pythonic by following through on your impulse to have a main function:

```
import os
import subprocess 

def main():
    cw = os.getcwd()
    path = '/scrape'
    ourPath = cw + os.path.join(path)

    if(ourPath):
        os.chdir(ourPath)
        os.system('scrapy crawl yellow')

if__name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Nice review! In the future please try to avoid answering off-topic questions. We try to close and finish those questions and answers really slow that down (and also send the wrong message to the asker). They are also probably likely to be mostly ignored with the post closed, anyway, so don't expect many upvotes (or any). Have a look at the [Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/should-you-refrain-from-answering-questions-that-are-likely-to-get-closed) for more reasons why obviously off-topic questions should not be answered.